# Bash script logging not working as expected with rsync jump server

Tags: bash, rsync, wait

I'm using a shell script below for doing some rsync on a remote host. By ssh to jumphost and from there ssh again and initiating the rsync as below.

Here I need to capture the log start and end date. But somehow when i executed below script, as it prints both log at the same time.

To be more precise, here the script spawns on ServerA , then jumping to ServerB, again it jumps to ServerC and then it hit the rsync command. Here I need to capture the start time and end time of rsync command on ServerA. But this end time which is not working as expected, once the script starts it keeps record the start and end time on logs.txt, but i can see the rsync process is still progressing.

```
date="`date +%T-%D`"
i=folder
echo "Log started at $date for $i" >> logs.txt
ssh -T -i key user1@HOST1  "ssh -T  user2@HOST2    << EOF
rsync -av --progress source dest
EOF"
###Here the logging not excecuting after the rsync command.
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo "Log ended at $date for $i" >> logs.txt
fi
```

Here i would need this script to be active once the rsync process to finish on the remote host and then it proceed to the log ended part.

I already tried the wait command, but this also not helped

Any ideas appreciated

Comment: I don't think you can just pass a heredoc to ssh? You'll at least need some thing like `ssh ... sh - <<EOF (newline) ... (newline) EOF`? (And in your case I don't even see the point to use heredoc.)

Comment: Does the `rsync` command actually work? You have set your script up to only report if it is successful, which seems a bit odd, you usually need to see the log when it fails more than when it is successful.

Comment: yes rsync command progressing in the backgroud. But without completing second echo printing

Comment: Hang on, in the background? Why is it in the background? How different is your actual script to what you've shown us here?

Comment: @terdon here the scenerio I'm invoking a rsync command to machine C, which jumps from A and then B ( jump host ) . I need to log the rsync start time and end time on Server A, where my script orginiates. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Yes, but you said rsync is running _in the background_ which is what I find confusing as I don't see (maybe because I am missing something obvious) what would send it to the background. In any case, your `if  [ $? -eq 0 ]; ` will only be true if `rsync` finishes successfully. So, if it is still running in the background when your script reaches the `if`, it will not be true and if the rsync failed it will not be true or if the ssh failed it won't be true.

Comment: @user183980, rsync is meant to compare HostA with HostC.  Unless you are using some kind of tunneling that connects HostA directly to HostC, in a manner that makes the intermediate HostB invisible to the rsync process, your approach is doomed to failure.  I believe your scenario is discussed here: https://superuser.com/questions/1115715/rsync-files-via-intermediate-host .